# Is there a URI scheme for opening a QR code app?

Tags: mobile, qr-code

I have a project that requires the browser to open a qr code reader app from a link. Is that possible? I know URI schemes are useful for this kind of situation, but I don't know where to look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no general solution, but, in specific cases, apps can register to handle certain links.

For example, Barcode Scanner on Android responds to `zxing://` links. So does the iOS app. See https://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningFromWebPages for details.

(It will also let you send back the results to a web page.)

It's possible that other apps also set up to follow this quasi-standard URI scheme, but it is not at all guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the exact app you want to open. There's no generic way.

QR Droid allows websites to use a link to open the app to scan, decode or generate a QR Code.

You can read more here:
http://qrdroid.com/web-masters.php

But as I said, you need to decide which app to use and then read the documentation for that specific app.